# who use the GADGET-2 pack for simulation? can I do it with my PC?

Tags: astrophysics, cosmology, radio-astronomy

I want to do hydrodynamic simulatin for universe at vary redshifts. How can I do it?
or how can I find an simulation of universe for use my work?

Comment: I see 4 questions here: 1. Who uses G2? 2. Can I use it with my PC? 3. How can I do hydrodynamic simulation etc? 4. Can I find a universe simulation? That's a bit much (e.g. Q1 is irrelevant). Please [edit] your question and tell us what problem you are facing *exactly*. And specify the architecture and OS of your PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gadget-2](https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/gadget/) is publicly available. Google works well to find it.
According to their website, it runs also on PCs. But don't get your hopes up, a single PC doesn't have enough computing power to simulate a whole universe. You'll need a bigger machine for that.

They have installation instructions on the webpage (see "Users Guide" under "Documentation"). You will possibly need a linux machine to run it, I don't know if the code compiles well under Windows.

Comment: also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GADGET#History) and [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0505010) (also [here](https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/gadget/gadget2-paper.pdf))